# Proving convergence of a sequence using an initial assumption that it does indeed converge. How to jump from step 5 to step 6?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, induction

**The proof is as follows:**

line 1: Suppose that $x_1 = 1$ and
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n +4}{x_n +1}$$

line 2: Suppose that $x_n$ converges to $s$; then the left-hand side of this equation converges to $s$ (by the shift rule), and the right-hand side of this equation converges to $\frac{s+4}{s+1}$ (by the quotient and sum rules, provided that $s \neq -1$). So, if $x_n \rightarrow s$, we would have
$$s = \frac{s+4}{s+1} \Rightarrow s(s+1)=s+4 \Rightarrow s^2 = 4 \Rightarrow s = \pm 2$$

line 3: Since the terms are positive, we guess that $x_n \rightarrow 2$; we now prove this. From before, we have
$$x_{n+1}-2 = \frac{x_n +4}{x_n +1} - 2 = \frac{x_n +4-2x_n -2}{x_n +1} = \frac{2-x_n}{x_n +1} = -\frac{x_n -2}{x_n +1}$$

line 4: We can prove that $x_n \ge 1$ for all $n$ by induction: it's true for $n = 1$ as $x_1 = 1$. If it's true for $n = k$, then $x_k \ge 1$, and so we have
$$x_{k+1} = \frac{x_k +4}{x_k +1} \ge 1$$

line 5: So we have $x_n \ge 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It now follows that
$$\vert{x_{n+1} -2}\vert = \frac{\vert{x_n -2}\vert}{\vert{x_n +1}\vert} \le \frac{1}{2} \vert{x_n -2}\vert$$

*The line below is the one I don't understand. More specifically, how do they generalize $\frac{1}{2}\vert{x_n -2}\vert$ into $2^{-n}\vert{x_1 -2}\vert$?*

line 6: so, we can say that
$$\vert{x_{n+1} -2}\vert \le 2^{-n}\vert{x_1 -2}\vert = 2^{-n} = (\frac{1}{2})^n $$

line 7: Therefore $x_n -2 \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, so $x_n \rightarrow 2$. $\square$

**Appendix:**

The shift rule :

Where $n, N \in \mathbb{N}$, it can be said that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}$ converges to a number if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_{n+N}}$ converges.

The quotient rule and sum rule:

Suppose that $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n \rightarrow b$. Then we can say that $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \rightarrow \frac{a}{b}$ and that $a_n + b_n \rightarrow a + b$, respectively.

Comment: In line 5, you have $|x_{n+1} - 2| \leq 0.5|x_n - 2|$. You can recursively apply this. $|x_{n+1} - 2| \leq 0.5|x_n - 2| \leq (0.5)^2 |x_{n-1} - 2| \leq (0.5)^3|x_{n-2} - 2| \leq \dots \leq 2^{-n}|x_1 - 2|$.